# Angular 5 array type casting

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I came across the following unusual scenario:

I have two models, for the purposes of this discussion, let them be **Car** and **Spaceship**.

I wrote a component with an input defined by the following constraint: This input is an array that can either be of type Car or Spaceship, **but not both**.
Thus, producing the following code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-stack-example',
    ...
})
export class StackExample{
    @Input() listOfVehicles: Array<Car> | Array<Spaceship> = [];

...
}
```

From my understanding this should be valid code, since I never want it to receive a mixed array. After doing some dev with the input set up as such, I ran into the following issue:

When modifying/accessing the array in any way (push(), splice(), indexOf(), find(), findIndex(), etc), eg:

```
this.listOfVehicles.push(new Car());
```

I get the following error:

```
TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: Car[]) => number) | ((...items: Spaceship[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: I don't think that is valid. In order to be able to `push` an instance of type `Car` you need `listOfVehicles` to be of concrete type `Array<Car>`, which is not guaranteed by the type of `listOfVehicles` as you define it.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov that makes sense. As H.B. suggested, I guess I'll just have to do something like declare it as Array<any> and initialize it as either new Array<Car> or <Spaceship> by means of another input. Ty!

Comment: To make your code more type-safe, you could declare a base class, e.g. `Vehicle` and then have both `Car` and `Spaceship` extend it, and make `listOfVehicles` of type `Array<Vehicle>`.

Comment: Ah yes, I've been contemplating that too, I could just have them inherit from a parent class since they have common fields...

Comment: GO ahead, from the OOP standpoint that would be the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not apparent to the compiler from the code what type the array currently has. So before using functions on the array, you probably would have to check types or cast the array to one of the two array types.

Essentially, your argument is not assignable to both possible types `push(item: Car)` and `push(item: Spaceship)` at the same time.